# Como usar icon SVG no addMarker (MarkerOptions) do Google Maps API Android

Tags: android, svg, google-maps-android-api-2, icons

Estou utilizando o seguinte código de Exemplo da documentação do **Google Maps API v2 para Android**:

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_bike))
                .anchor(0.0f, 1.0f) // Anchors the marker on the bottom left
                .position(new LatLng(41.889, -87.622)));
```

Funcionou muito bem para imagens **.PNG**, porem no meu APP só estou utilizando ícones e imagens em **.SVG** criadas pelo próprio *Vector Asset do Android Studio 3*, e gostaria de manter esse padrão em todo o aplicativo, mas não conseguir fazer o addMarker aceitar meus arquivos .SVG...

Encontrei a seguinte pergunta no Stackoverflow em Inglês, mas nenhuma resposta funcionou pra mim:

[Custom marker in google maps in android with vector asset icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42365658/custom-marker-in-google-maps-in-android-with-vector-asset-icon)

Preciso deixar claro, que minha necessidade é pegar um arquivo .svg dos diretórios **res/drawable** e incluir como parâmetro do método **icon()** da classe **MarkerOptions()** do Google Maps API v2 p/ Android, por favor só responda se a solução for para esse uso.

Se possível, faça um teste criando qualquer icone .svg no Vector Asset do Android Studio e inclua esse arquivo como icone no MarkerOptions, se funcionar ai no seu Maps, você tem a solução que eu procuro.

Obs:

- Meus SVG foram criados corretamente e estão todos funcionais, não é problema nos arquivos svg.
- Estou seguindo esse [Guia da Documentação do Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start)
- A activity do Mapa esta funcional com icones Bitmap padrão (PNG).
- Os testes estão sendo feitos em um (dispositivo físico) Tablet Samsung 7" com Android versão 4.4.4 SDK 19.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escreva um método para obter um BitmapDescriptor

```
private BitmapDescriptor getBitmapDescriptorFromVectorDrawable(int id) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        VectorDrawable vectorDrawable = (VectorDrawable) getDrawable(id);

        int h = vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
        int w = vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth();

        vectorDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, w, h);

        Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bm);
        vectorDrawable.draw(canvas);

        return BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bm);

    } else {
        return BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(id);
    }
}
```

Altere o seu código para usar o método:

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .icon(getBitmapDescriptorFromVectorDrawable(R.drawable.ic_bike))
                .anchor(0.0f, 1.0f) // Anchors the marker on the bottom left
                .position(new LatLng(41.889, -87.622)));
```

**Nota:** O id passado a `getBitmapDescriptorFromVectorDrawable()` tem de ser de um VectorDrawable(SVG).

Fonte: [Get BitmapDescriptor from a VectorDrawable resource for use as an icon on a Google Map Marker.](https://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/1056453/Get-BitmapDescriptor-from-a-VectorDrawab)

Comment: Estou recebendo o seguinte erro: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 18696: L com/example/myfirstapp/ViewMapsActivity;.getDrawable (I)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;...
E/AndroidRuntime(10017):  at com.example.myfirstapp.ViewMapsActivity.onMapReady(ViewMapsActivity.java:87)... Depois disso o APP para, assim como os outros exemplos que testei e citei na pergunta.

Comment: O código foi testado na versão 4.4.2 e 7.0. Esse erro que refere parece-me ser devido à utilização de um método que não existe na versão do dispositivo, o método só existe numa versão superior da do dispositivo. Como isso é outro problema faça uma nova pergunta, inclua o código do mapa e do arquivo gradle.